# Dates compare with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following form:

```
<form action = "dt.jsp" METHOD = "GET" ONSUBMIT="return validateForm()">
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><input type=date name="fdate"/></td>
     <td><input type=date name="tdate"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input  TYPE = "SUBMIT" VALUE = "Search by date">
</form>
```

I am validating the form using a date comparison function I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript/497790#497790) and the following function:

```
 function validateForm()
 {
   if(dates.compare(document.getElementsByName('fdate')[0].value,
                 document.getElementsByName('tdate')[0].value) == -1)
 {
    alert("to date must be bigger then from date");
    return false;
 }
 }
```

What is the problem of this code?

Comment: I don't know. Do you?

Comment: no... I ask the question...

Comment: if you can't explain what's wrong, how are we supposed to guess? We don't know what `dates` is, or what `dates.compare()` does. In short there isn't enough information here for this to be a valid question

Comment: dates.compare is javascript function to compare date (from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript) but it don't work in my case...
can you suggest me another way to compare this two dates?

Comment: What format are you entering the date info in? The code you are using parses date strings by just passing them into the `Date` constructor. The `Date` constructor expects a [very specific format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). I suspect it is not working because the date strings you are handing it do not conform to that format, thus `Date` is not producing a valid date object which is causing the comparison function to fail.

Comment: Something else that would help with answering this question is **how** it isn't working. Is it always submitting despite having invalid dates? Is it never submitting even when it has dates that should pass the validation?

Answer (score 0):

The [code you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497790/778975) parses date strings by just passing them into the `Date` constructor. The `Date` constructor expects a [very specific format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). I suspect it is not working because the date strings you are handing it do not conform to that format, thus `Date` is not producing a valid date object which is causing the comparison function to fail.

When dealing with dates [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is often very helpful. In this case it could make your not only more flexible but much more readable. Moment will allow you to [provide a list](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) of acceptable [date formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) it will use to parse the date strings you provide it. It also provides a number of methods for comparing dates such as [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/).

Using these your code could be rewritten to something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  var acceptedFormats = ["MM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MM", "DD-MM-YYYY"],
    fromDate = moment(document.getElementsByName('fdate')[0].value, acceptedFormats),
    toDate = moment(document.getElementsByName('tdate')[0].value, acceptedFormats);

  if (fromDate.isAfter(toDate)) { // much more readable, it's practically a sentence!
    alert("To Date must be after From Date");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Something else I just noticed, your code will always fail to submit the form even if the date comparison passes. When the comparison fails you explicitly return `false` which stops the form from submitting. But when the test passes you don't return anything, implicitly returning `undefined`. When `undefined` is passed into the submit handler `ONSUBMIT="return validateForm()"`, it will be coerced into `false`, also causing the form to not submit.